# How to show that this space is not a manifold?

Tags: general-topology, manifolds

Define $X = (\mathbb{R}^2 \backslash \{0\})/\sim$ with the quotient topology induced by the projection $\pi: \mathbb{R}^2\backslash \{0\} \rightarrow X$ where the equivalence relation $\sim$ on $\mathbb{R}^2 \backslash \{0\}$ is given by $(x,y) \sim (\lambda^{-1} x, \lambda y)$ for some $\lambda \in \mathbb{R}\backslash\{0\}$.

How would you show that X is not a manifold?

Comment: It's not Hausdorff: You cannot separate $[0,1]$ from $[1,0]$

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen I have a hard time understanding the topology of X and visualizing it... Maybe could you extend your comment to an answer so that I have something to accept?

Answer (score 2):

Hagen von Eitzen is correct, $X$ is not Hausdorff because $[(0,1)]$ and $[(1,0)]$ cannot be seperated by disjoint open sets in $X$.

Here is a proof.  Consider the sequences $x_n, y_n$ of points in $\mathbb{R}^2\setminus 0$ given by $x_n = \left(\frac{1}{n},1\right)$ and $y_n = \left(1, \frac{1}{n}\right)$.

We clearly have $x:=\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} x_n = (0,1)$ and $y:=\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} y_n = (1,0)$.

Now, since $\pi$ is continuous, we see that $\pi(x_n)$ converges to $\pi(x)$.  Likewise, $\pi(y_n)$ converges to $\pi(y)$.

But note the following two points:

1. $\pi(x)\neq \pi(y)$.  This is because if $(0,1) = (\lambda^{-1} 1, \lambda 0)$ for some $\lambda \in \mathbb{R}\setminus 0$, then the second coordinate gives $1 = 0$, an obvious contradiction.
2. $\pi(x_n) = \pi(y_n)$ for all $n$.  To see this, set $\lambda = n$.  Then $[y_n] = [(1,1/n)] = [ (\lambda^{-1}, \lambda/n)] = [(1/n, 1)] = [x_n]$.

Point 1 says the two sequences $\pi(x_n)$ and $\pi(y_n)$ have two different limits and Point 2 says the two sequences $\pi(x_n)$ and $\pi(y_n)$ are really the same sequence.  So, the one sequence $\pi(x_n) = \pi(y_n)$ has two distinct limits.  This cannot occur in a Hausdorff space.

Comment: I see that my final contradiction is to "Hausdorff" where I originally made a stronger claim in my first sentence.  But in any space, Hausdorff or not, if you have a sequence converging to two different points $p,q$, those points cannot be separated by disjoint open sets: if $U$ is a neigborhood of $p$ and $V$ is a neighborhood of $q$, then by definition of convergence both $U$ and $V$ contain all but finitely many elements of the sequence.  Removing these "finitely many", we are left with an infinite portion of the sequence lying in both $U$ and $V$, so $U$ and $V$ are not disjoint.